# Is it possible to implement some pre-process or something to check if it bean name present in Enum

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to check bean name by Enum name which was delivered from resources? There is Eanum where declared all available bean names which were configured in the project

```
public enum ClientBeanNames {
    DIRECT("direct-http-client"),
    STATISTIC("statistic-http-client");
}
```

and application resource

```
app:
  clients:
    direct:
      http-client: direct-http-client
    statistic:
      http-client: statistic-http-client
```

and my service where I want to inject some of the implementations by bean name

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Statistic {

    @Resource(name = "${app.clients.statistic.http-client}")
    private Client httpClient;
```

and finally configuration class

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class HttpClientConfiguration {

@Bean(name = "direct-http-client")
public SplitSdkHttpClient direct() {
    return new DirectHttpClient();
}

@Bean(name = "statistic-http-client")
@Profile("statistic")
public HttpClient statistic() throws Exception {
    return new StatisticHttpClient();
}
```

Is it possible to implement some pre-process or something to check if it bean name present in eanum ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a kind of post-check monitor:

```
public class Monitor implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
        // run any checks you need
    }
}
```

With `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor` you can gain even more details and controls before beans actual initialisation.